# How to bill my customers that are using my Azure cloud service?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, azure

I have a WCF RESTful application hosted on an Azure cloud service and I need to know how to bill my customers that are using my service.

Actually I want to bill them by the bandwidth comsumption. I mean to consider only the HTTP response package.

Is there a way to get the bandwidth comsumption in my application, so that I can register it, and later on, send an invoice for each customer?

Someone could post here a code sample?

Regards,

Comment: You could turn on IIS logging then parse the results. Maybe another option could be adding a performance counter.

Comment: I'm not sure but WCF Performance Counters might help get you the information you're looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735098.aspx

Comment: BTW, what we do is price our services in two ways: by weighted call and "unlimited" (where they get throttled to slower speeds if they hammer us too fast). We assign a cost from 0-100. Most simple/quick calls cost ~1-5. Some heavy ones cost ~20+. Some "Report" type calls cost 100. What these "points" result in as far as money is concerned is on a tiered basis. Ultimately, the "unlimited" package is everybody's favorite since it's predictable and less complicated.

Answer (score 6):

I think the easiest way (and very reliable) of doing that would be gather Azure Web Role IIS logs and parse them, getting number of bytes sent to specific clients.

There is very nice article [Analyzing 1 TB of IIS logs with Hadoop Map/Reduce on Azure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benjguin/archive/2012/02/09/analyzing-1-tb-of-iis-logs-with-hadoop-map-reduce-on-azure-with-javascript-analyse-d-1-to-de-journaux-iis-avec-hadoop-map-reduce-en-javascript.aspx) describing similar process.

I hope that will be helpful.